Looker - How to Compare today data with last week data but including hours
I need to find out how to compare today data with last week data in lookerstudio.
Example:
Today 01/11/2024 16.00 PM # of order is 2255
Last week 25/10/2024 16.00 PM # of order is 2190
I need to compare those 2255 and 2190. Only showing 2190 also fine for me. I just need to see 2190 but I need those comparison in everytime. Second example:
Today 01/11/2024 16.05 PM # of order is 2295
Last week 25/10/2024 16.05 PM # of order is 2211.
Any help?

You can use this sql,
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), TIMESTAMP(order_date), DAY) = 0 -- for last week make it 7 
         AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM order_date) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
         AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM order_date) = EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    THEN order_count
    ELSE NULL 
END

OR you can create a calculation, like this,
if(
    diff_days(${order_date}, now()) = 0 -- for last week make it 7
    AND extract_hours(${order_date}) = extract_hours(now())
    AND extract_minutes(${order_date}) = extract_minutes(now()),
    ${order_count}, null
)

